# EntityManagerException while running in Travis CI, Spring Boot and PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-boot, travis-ci

I made a simple web application using Spring Boot, PostgreSQL, Maven and JUnit. While running it in my IDE (mvn clear-verify) everything works perfect but while running in Travis CI I got this exception:

> Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory

and a lot of others. My tests run perfect as well in IDE. Can someone tell me why? My code is here:

Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "contacts")
public class Contact extends BaseEntity{

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    public Contact() {
    }
    public Contact(String name) {
        this(null,name);
    }
    public Contact(Integer id, String name) {
        super(id);
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Contact{" +
                "id='" + id + '\'' +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Repository:

```
@Repository
public class ContactRepositoryImpl implements ContactRepository{

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ContactRepositoryImpl.class);

    @Autowired
    private ProxyContactRepository proxyContactRepository;

    private Pattern regexPattern;

    @Override
    public List<Contact> getAllSorted(String nameFilter) {
        List<Contact> listOfAllContacts = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();
        try {
            regexPattern = Pattern.compile(nameFilter);
            if (!nameFilter.isEmpty() || nameFilter.length() != 0) {
                listOfAllContacts.addAll(getAll().stream().filter(contact -> notDoMatch(contact.getName())).collect(Collectors.toList()));
            } else {
                LOG.warn("Regex parameter " + "'" + nameFilter + "'" + " is empty");
                throw new NotFoundException("Regex parameter is empty");
            }
            return listOfAllContacts;
        }
        catch (PatternSyntaxException exception){
            LOG.error("Regex parameter " + "'" + nameFilter + "'" + " is invalid");
            throw new NotFoundException("Regex parameter is invalid");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public List<Contact> getAll() {
        return proxyContactRepository.findAll();
    }

    private boolean notDoMatch(String word){
        Matcher matcher = regexPattern.matcher(word);
        return !matcher.matches();
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/contacts")
public class ContactController extends AbstractContactController{

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, params = "nameFilter")
    public List<Contact> getSortedPage(@RequestParam("nameFilter") String nameFilter){
        return super.getAllSorted(nameFilter);
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<Contact> getAllPage(){
        return super.getAll();
    }
}
```

travis.yml

```
language: java
script: mvn clean verify
jdk: oraclejdk8

services:
- postgresql

before_script:
- psql -c 'create database hello;' -U postgres
```

And app.properties:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/hello
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=password

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL81Dialect
```

[image]
I checked the connection to PostgreSQL DB and it works (you can see it on picture), but I do not have Entity Manager in Test.
Can somebody tell my what is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use H2 for integration testing instead of PostgreSQL. You don't need to setup any TravisCI service. You test suite will be much more maintainable and not dependent on external service. You can also use [H2's compatibility mode with PostgreSQL](http://h2database.com/html/features.html#compatibility).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I want to know, how can I avoid this exception using PostgreSQL.

Comment: I fixed my problem. I have divided my project into two profiles (test and release)  and created to each profile its own database. In that way I have PostgreSQL database for 'release' profile and H2 database for 'test' profile, becuase as I faund out Travis uses embedded database while runing project. Thanks @luboskmac.